# Error in writing a data frame to an uncompressed parquet file in hdfs

Tags: apache-spark

i have  used the below codes

```
df.write.format("parquet").option("compression","none").mode("overwrite").save("/asdf")  

df.write.option("compression","snappy").save("/mmmm")
                                       ^
```

and i am getting the compressed file

/asdfh/part-r-00001-bcadb2e0-8ae1-4170-86f2-3dd42460bdd4.gz.parquet

Comment: second code i have tried to use snappy compression

Comment: What is the error log information?